# ng-view load a new separate page in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call an rest api, which does the does the login process, in angular.

I have successfully, integrated the angular with my rest calls. Once the login is successful, I want the code to move to new page.

In my successful handler, I'm doing this:

```
$location.path("/home")
```

And I have my route provide like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
```

and in my view I have an html tag like this:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Things are working fine as expected. But I want the `ng-view` to be load a complete new page, rather only template. As from the login page, I need to move to new page.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you donot want to open the html into ng-view then set `location.href = url` or `window.location = url`
Or use angular way `$window.location=url;`

Comment: if u open html in separate page that page need to include the angular js main files as its kind of fresh page.. and route will not work as its kind of out of route. Best is keep same page and hide other things with ng-show if its only about ui look n feel but you wana keep functionality of route.

Comment: So your saying I need to hide the login form using `ng-show`? And then make my new page appear over there?

Comment: i mean, hide the login from ng-show, and call page with route as before. But its kind of give look and feel of new page. can u explain why u want new page ?

Comment: There is a login page, lets say user have logged in successfully. I have to take to here new page right, the home page?

Comment: its not necessary if login process in ajax, you can show home page there only. But i m not clear why u need new page redirection, until u posting form and some server specific work which can't handle in client through ajax.

Comment: Hmm ya that make sense to me. So after login, I can hide the login page using `ng-show` and show my new div, which is my home page. Now does that make sense?

Comment: yes or keep the login as one view which is with separate controller and login service, once login success (on some ng-click).. change the view to home.